Setup Llama LLM model and invoke it using Amazon API Gateway, But not working

Setup Amazon SageMaker Studio domain



Setting up Llama-7B model and creating an endpoint for the model


Send prompts to your Llama2 LLM model. Run the commands mentioned in the notebook.


Create a Lambda function to invoke the endpoint




Created an API getaway.


I get an error message When I try to access it using Postman.



How can I debug and fix this issue?

Are you able to look at Cloudwatch logs for the Lambda function and the endpoint? The endpoint logs may be helpful to figure out the reason for the Internal Server Error.
